# Access main menus without using the mouse

Tags: interface, shortcut, select, mouse

I am new to blender and there is something I couldn't find in the documents. How can I access all the main menus and sub-menus just using the keyboard? I read the documentation on menus and there it is very well describe how to access all sub-menus, but I couldn't find how to open the main menus in order to use the underscored letters the key-pad, the mouse wheel or the arrows. Is there a way to activate, for example, the File menu without using the mouse, so I can then press "I" in order to open the Import sub-menu and then "T" to import a Stl file?

Comment: You will in some ways be disappointed if you are someone who prefers short-cut keys instead of a mouse, in this very arcane 3d modelling world (blender, 3ds Max, etc).   You can visit Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap to investigate shortcuts.  I'm not sure if there is some cheat-sheet somewhere (I gave up looking).  Export to Python script is not what you'd hope for.  Each manual page shows the Shortcut for that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't the answer you are hoping for, but the answer is that it is not possible to open the top menu in blender with any sort of keyboard short cut key.

It would be nice if this feature was added in my opinion, there has been discussions about it in the past, but one of the issues is the limited number of available hot keys, hot keys like ctrl-f or alt-f are already taken, and the developers have a rule about not taking away hot keys from existing projects if something has already been taken because that would be showing some sort of favoritism.

Normally the short cut to open the top menu would be the letter that is underlined, but as you can see, in blender none of the letters of the top menu are underlined, because there is no short cut key to open them directly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It **is** possible to simulate this using just one extra keypress to bring up the Quick Favorites menu but you do need the mouse to set things up initially!
Right-click on each top menu item in turn and choose "Add to Quick Favorites"
[image]

When you subsequently press the <kbd>Q</kbd> key you'll find that all your menus have been added to the Quick Menu **including** the conventional underlines for the hotkeys.
[image]

Pressing the hotkey then brings up the submenu as usual and you can use key presses to access the submenu items.
[image]

So once things are set up just press <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the Import dialog. - No mouse clicks at all!